# Invalid Postback or Callback Error - How to find what is causing the error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, callback

I'm working on an asp.net web application and am running into this error after manipulating some controls client-side (html buttons nested in update panels):

**"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."**

The stack trace given is:

**"[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]**

**System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +9832822
System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +114
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +65
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +18
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +471
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1897"**

This stack trace is useless in that it's not telling me what control is causing the issue.  I think I understand the basics of what the error is trying to say, but without a direction to go it's a total crapshoot as to where to start looking, particularly since I'm not manipulating any dropdown lists.

Before I go through the hassle of posting code, how can I get the complete stack trace (showing file and line number) for the error to figure out what is happening?  I've been working on this problem for a week now and I'm pretty well fed up with it.  Thanks.

Comment: hum, does this occur on a button click? Try moving any control valiadtors to the top of the page, see if that helps. I guess a few more details as to "when" the error occurs. (does it occur on first page load, or due to some button click? And do you have any say JavaScript bits and parts that might have posted the page back before it is 100% rendered?  I mean, something added to the page must have "started" this issue to occur. but, we quite much guessing. You could as a test in web config turn off page validation, and at least see if that works, and then try to fix and then re-enable.

Answer (score 0):

hum, does this occur on a button click? Try moving any control validators to the top of the page, see if that helps. I guess a few more details as to "when" the error occurs. (does it occur on first page load, or due to some button click? And do you have any say JavaScript bits and parts that might have posted the page back before it is 100% rendered? I mean, something added to the page must have "started" this issue to occur. but, we quite much guessing. You could as a test in web config turn off page validation, and at least see if that works, and then try to fix and then re-enable.

Also, are you loading up data into some controls on page load?

Try then placing that "setup" and "data loading" inside of the !IsPostback (which all pages quite much need and have, right??).

So, in page load event, place that data load, and setup code you have inside of the !IsPostBack block like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
    page load + setup + data loading code goes here
}
```

So, adopt the above if you have code to load up say a gridview, or even a dropdown box. I seen the above "simple" change in code fix your error, and a good number of times.